# Inserir valor de input em array

Tags: php, html

Como armazenar os valores de um input em posições de um array? Gostaria de pegar o valor que foi digitado no campo e armazenar em um array, onde preciso ordenar os valores que foram adicionados no array e ordená-los de forma decrescente.

Ex:

```
<?PHP
echo"<tr>
   <td>
     <input type="text" name="campos" value="">
   </td>
   <td>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
   </td>
</tr>";
?>
```

Comment: Estás a gerar vários inputs no servidor com PHP é isso? e depois queres no JavaScript guardar os valores inseridos num array certo? e depois queres usar o array no JavaScript ou no PHP?

Comment: Na verdade estou a gerar a um único input no PHP, onde estou querendo pegar os valores inseridos nele e armazenar em um array no PHP! Acabei não criando vários inputs, pois estou vendo uma maneira de usar um único input para inserir os dados!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basta colocar o nome do campo com chaves no final.`nomedocampo[]`. Daí supondo que isso seja um formulário, quando vc enviar com um post para o backend.

o backend vai entender que esse conjunto de campos com o mesmo nome é um array e transformará isso num único objeto `$_POST['nomedocampo']`

```html
<input type="text" name="campos[]" value="">

<input type="text" name="campos[]" value="">

<input type="text" name="campos[]" value="">


<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

Comment: Era isso mesmo que eu estava precisando!