# Preciso pegar os filhos de um elemento

Tags: php, post

Eu preciso pegar o valor dos inputs com ID `nome` e `sobrenome`, porem quando uso `$_POST`, ele vai retornar apenas o primeiro, e eu preciso de todos separadamente.

```
<form method="POST">
  <tr id = "0">
    <td>
      <input id="nome"/>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input id="sobrenome"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id = "1">
    <td>
      <input id="nome"/>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input id="sobrenome"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id = "2">
    <td>
      <input id="nome"/>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input id="sobrenome"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: O que você entende por "pegar"? Você refere-se ao valor digitado nos campos? Se sim, utilize a global `$_POST` do PHP.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Atualizada a pergunta.

Comment: Ok. Primeiro, o atributo `id` define elementos únicos na página, então criar múltiplos elementos com mesmo `id` não faz sentido. Segundo, define os atributos `name` dos campos e adicione `[]` ao final. Por exemplo: `<input name="nome[]" />"`, desta forma `$_POST['name']` será a lista com todos os nomes preenchidos. É isso que necessita?

Comment: Poderia colocar isso como resposta por favor ?? resolveu meu problema.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Inserir valor de input em array](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/150225/inserir-valor-de-input-em-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IDs são identificadores únicos, não podem ser duplicados.

Insira o atributo "name" na tag input e defina o valor como "nome[ ]". Ficaria assim:

`<input name="nome[]"/>`

Isso criaria um array com todos os valores preenchidos.